# RealmException: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 1

Tags: android, realm

I'm receiving a new error in my logcat from Realm, when the application tries to save a json inside realm "io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 1" error comes out

I have searched in internet but all answers I have found were for Value already exists: 0.
I have tried different types of calls as insert a realm.clear() before  createAllFromJson() or change createAllFromJson for createOrUpdateAllFromJson but it isn't working. 
Does anyone of you know what is number 1 refers to?

Here is the code -->

```
if (null != realm) {
            try {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                //realm.clear(StationRealm.class);
                realm.createAllFromJson(StationRealm.class, json);
                //realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(StationRealm.class, json);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                sendStatusRefreshedMessage(context);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                realm.cancelTransaction();
                Log.e(TAG, "RealmDBStations: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

StationRealm.class -->

```
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = { StationRealm.class })
@RealmClass
public class StationRealm extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String addressNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    private String districtCode;
    private String districtName;
    private double altitude;
    private String stationType;
    private LocationRealm location;
    private int bikes;
    private int slots;
    private double distanceTo;

    public StationRealm() {};

    public StationRealm(StationRealm station) {
        this.id = station.getId();
        this.name = station.getName();
        this.address = station.getAddress();
        this.addressNumber = station.getAddressNumber();
        this.zipCode = station.getZipCode();
        this.districtCode = station.getDistrictCode();
        this.districtName = station.getDistrictName();
        this.altitude = station.getAltitude();
        this.stationType = station.getStationType();
        this.location = station.getLocation();
        this.bikes = station.getBikes();
        this.slots = station.getSlots();
        this.distanceTo = station.getDistanceTo();
    }
// getters and setters
}
```

Json -->

```
[{"id":1,"name":"1 - Allen Street","address":"XXX","addressNumber":"0","zipCode":"11","districtCode":"1","districtName":"","altitude":null,"nearbyStations":[2,3,69],"location":{"lat":41.674,"lon":-0.967},"stationType":"BIKE"},{"id":2,"name":"2 - XXX","address":"XXX","addressNumber":"0","zipCode":"11","districtCode":"1","districtName":"","altitude":null,"nearbyStations":[1,3,69],"location":{"lat":41.66,"lon":-0.86},"stationType":"BIKE"}]
```

I have tried some new cases:
If I insert a json like this -->

```
[{"id":1,"name":"1 - Allen Street","address":"XXX","addressNumber":"0","zipCode":"11","districtCode":"1","districtName":"","altitude":null,"nearbyStations":[2,3,69],"location":{"lat":41.674,"lon":-0.967},"stationType":"BIKE"}]
```

The error is the same, but if I change the id 1 for id 2 the error changes and shows io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 2.

The realm is clean how can exist another id:2?

Comment: Your StationRealm class contains a primary key. Your JSON that you are parsing contains more than one object with the primary key field equal to 1. Print the json string to see it.

Comment: I have checked and there is only one "id":1

Comment: please share your json and `StationRealm.class` ;)

Comment: You've defined `id` as a string, but the JSON is an integer. If you change the declaration to `private int id` does the problem go away?

Comment: Use `createOrUpdateAllFromJson` instead

Comment: I have tried also and it isn`t working, the only solution was make a clear of the Stations.class before create anything